# Something wrong with php code

Tags: php, mysql

I did something wrong because the last lane do not add anything to database.
Could someone experienced take a look please?

EDIT: I just deleted all unnecessary lanes

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO votes (voter, photoid, photoowner, vote) VALUES ($voter, $photoid, $photoowner, "yes")');
```

Comment: Which error's do you get? And where is your DB connection?

Comment: Do you set `$photoid` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Well.. For starters u are using `$photoid` in the first query but only define it on the next line. Also this is wide open for SQL injection

Comment: I am connecting correctly because the first my_query lane works good. I added today last 5 lanes but they do not work :(
I dont see any errors

Comment: Single quotes on the last `mysql_query` prevent your variables (**$voter**, etc.) from being evaluated. They just remain variable name strings.

Comment: So what can I do in this case?

Comment: @Helloitsme you can read the answer i gave you...

Comment: @Konstantin Thank you but it still not working :( I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you values for $voter, $photoid, $photoowner numeric?

Comment: Mysql Error says that my problem is with , 'yes' syntax
No, inside my variables are strings mostly

Comment: You're obviously trying to pass a string; quote your variables.

Comment: is your `vote` column varchar or text?

Comment: @Helloitsme Just a word of *friendly* advice. It's best to let everyone know in a question, exactly what type of data is being passed. In this case it seemed to me that it's related to "files" and maybe even a person's name. Having only a single line of code, isn't enough to properly diagnose the problem. I'm telling you this for future questions you may have, and should also include "exact and full" error messages you may have gotten. Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and checking for errors on the query are helpful tools when developing *wink*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable values are not evaluated within a string with single quotes:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO votes (voter, photoid, photoowner, vote) VALUES ('$voter', '$photoid', '$photoowner', 'yes')");
```

put double quotes around your select statement or use concatenation and don't forget to put **quotes around your string values**

Also use use mysql_error() to retrieve the error text

Comment: I will try this tank you :D

Comment: i don't understand the downvotes, must be jealousy of my superior typing skills :)

Comment: People always downwote a lot :(
Anyway, i just copied your code but its still not working im not sure how it should be done exactly :X

Comment: Just pasting a code of line is not an answer imho

Comment: @DarkBee just looking at things is not the same as seeing... the line is different in a very crucial way

Comment: I see the line is different, but your initial post was only a single line. This is not helping the OP if you don't point out what he was doing wrong. Anyway downvote revoked after u  added the extra information

Comment: I have quoted all variables and its working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Helloitsme It's up to the person who answered to modify the code. I gave you a comment to that effect. Being [this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453093/something-wrong-with-php-code#comment43344885_27453093)

Comment: @Fred -ii- yea but i am still not able to vode your answers and comments because low reputation. Everyone disliking my questions :(

Comment: @Helloitsme I didn't downvote anybody, in case anyone is wondering.